# Title of horror novel book where the villain is actually twins raised to believe they were one person?

Tags: story-identification, horror

When I was an early teen in the early to mid 80's I was a horror junkie.  I came across a novel in which the bad guy, a serial killer, turns out to have been twins actually raised by their mother to believe that they were both the same person, in two bodies.

Somewhere late in the book one of the twins is killed, leaving the other in tremendous distress.

That's about all I can remember - anyone know the title?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The name of the novel is "*Whispers*", written in 1990 by Dean Koontz.

Wiki site [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whispers_(novel)):

serial killer, turns out to have been twins actually raised by their mother to believe that they were both the same person, in two bodies.

> MATCH: Katherine gave birth to identical twin boys. The twins were born with cauls on their faces, leading the mentally unstable Katherine to believe they were demons. She raised her sons as if they were one person. They were both called Bruno, and both were rewarded or punished for anything either one of them did.

Somewhere late in the book one of the twins is killed,

> PARTIAL MATCH (This actually occurs relatively early in the book): The next day Frye returns and attacks Hilary again, this time receiving several stab wounds before escaping. She calls the police and once again meets with Clemenza, who tells her that Frye's body has been found and takes her to the morgue to identify it.

Comment: This also doesn't match with the OP's time-frame memory.

Comment: Whispers was published in 1980, according to Wikipedia, so it fits the timeframe.

Comment: Parallax is spot on with the answer. Anyone that has read it will recognize it. Dean Koontz at his finest.  The only bad thing about it is that they made it into a movie :-)